# How is sassafras used in flavoring?

Tags: seasoning

I have several large sassafras trees that I would like to use for flavoring. What part of the tree is used? How is it prepared? How is it used?

Comment: Oh that's a real word? I thought Tenacious D was just making things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, [using sassafras root as a flavoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sassafras#Culinary_uses) might not be a good idea. Leaves can be dried and ground to make filé powder, used to thicken gumbo.

Comment: [Filé powder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fil%C3%A9_powder) is not just a thickener; the article describes it as "spicy" and "earthy". And to be clear, the summary is: use the leaves, not the root, and not the bark.

Comment: People used to use roots and bark.